# NSURL with special characters (åäö)

Tags: php, iphone, ios, nsurl

I have some images on my server, named with special characters (å,ä,ö). I can't figure out how to convert the NSUrl to get them:

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @".../Images/%@Image.png", playerName]; 

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"url:%@", url);

    //Get the image and assign it to the player
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

The log in the above example (if "playerName" = åäö):

```
.../Images/%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6Image.png
```

but I need it to be:

```
.../Images/åäöImage.png
```

I tried different (stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding) and the code below without success:

```
- (NSString *)URLEncodingOfString:(NSString *)s
{
return (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes
(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)s, NULL, NULL,
 kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1);
 }
```

Any advice is very appreciated, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of web server hosts the file? Apache? I assume your web browser fetches it fine when you put the file name in the URL bar. What web browser are you using? (The reason I ask the client and server question is so that we can investigate what encoding each one uses by default.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Yup, when I type it in in the browser it works nice.. And it also works from the iphone with the NSURL without any special characters... It just the NSURL converts the special characters to some other stuff that causes the problem..

Comment: @BlackMouse hi, have you found any solution?

Comment: @BlackMouse i'm facing the same problem which was eating most of the time in my app, any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I think it'll depend entirely on what encoding the web server is using.

Since ISO-Latin-1 doesn't seem, from your test, to work, you might try replacing `kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1` with `kCFStringEncodingUTF8`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
    kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1 );
```

Unfortunately, the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method doesn't encode all special characters properly.

Source: [How to really URL encode an NSString in Objective-C, iPhone, etc.](http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/)

**EDIT:**

Have you tried

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @".../Images/%@Image.png", playerName]; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
```

Note the `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Comment: I have just edited the answer with something else you can try

Comment: Thanks.. I tried it, and still get the wrong url: Images/jag%E4rdator.png  (If the name is jagärdator.png)

Comment: The value of the log is correct: you are logging the encoded string. Your server, however, should understand this encoded url and find the corresponding image. Is your NSData being created properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

To create NSURL

```
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:stringURL];
```

The stringURL is the string representing URL. While logging, try this

```
 NSLog("%@",[url absoluteString]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue due to "%C3%89%C3%89" which converts to ÉÉ within a url I was attempting to load. This seemed to convert the url into the desired format to allow me to download the file from the URL.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[imageURL stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```